# Excel - counting how many consecutive 0s in a row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have multiple ‘people’ in rows in excel, with 10+ columns of system usage data. I want the final column to show how many consecutive months have 0 usage. For example, person a might have had 0 usage in March and April, used in June, then 0 usage in July - December, I would need the end column to show 6.

Comment: Please see [ask] a question with an [mcve] and edit your question to include your own attempt to solve the issue. That way we can help you debugging and/or propose other options. Right now, this is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is from `B2` to `M2` you could use the following formula:
`=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(B2:M2=0,COLUMN(B2:M2)),IF(B2:M2<>0,COLUMN(B2:M2))))`

This will show the max number of consecutive 0's in that row 2 from column B to M.

[image]

Older versions of Excel require this array formula entered with `ctrl+shift+enter`

If you want the formula to show the quantity of consecutive zeroes of the last occurance in the row then you could use:
`=LOOKUP(2,1/(FREQUENCY(IF($B2:$M2=0,COLUMN($B2:$M2)),IF($B2:$M2<>0,COLUMN($B2:$M2)))>0),FREQUENCY(IF($B2:$M2=0,COLUMN($B2:$M2)),IF($B2:$M2<>0,COLUMN($B2:$M2))))`

Comment: This almost works for me! Is there a way to do it for the numbers to only show if the last column is 0. For example, N3 is 2, however that’s counting the 2 0s that are together further up. Whereas I only want a number there if the last month is 0, and the consecutive ones before that

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you mean by `a way to do it for the numbers to only show if the last column is 0.`. Do you mean `IF(M2=0,MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(B2:M2=0,COLUMN(B2:M2)),IF(B2:M2<>0,COLUMN(B2:M2)))),"")` ?

Comment: Almost! The issue I have with that is that it finds the maximum number of zeros. For example if January - July are all 0, august is 6, september is 5, and November and December are both 0. It will show 7(accounting for Jan-July) instead of 2.

Comment: Ok, it wasn't clear from the question that you wanted the consecutive count of zeros that are most right in certain row. In that case you can use `=LOOKUP(2,1/(FREQUENCY(IF($B2:$M2=0,COLUMN($B2:$M2)),IF($B2:$M2<>0,COLUMN($B2:$M2)))>0),FREQUENCY(IF($B2:$M2=0,COLUMN($B2:$M2)),IF($B2:$M2<>0,COLUMN($B2:$M2))))` make sure you enter with `ctrl+shift+enter` if you use older Excel. Else consider using LET to name the `FREQUENCY()` part of the formula.

Answer (score 0):

I've made something for you, based on the numbers of the months in the year: 1-12 (in column "item").
In the "Value" column, there are the values zero or else.
The "Length" column contains the number of subsequent zeroes, based on following formulas:

- First entry : `=IF(B2=0,1,0)`
- Following entries: `=IF(B3=0,C2+1,0)`

Screenshot:

[image]

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

This might help if 2 is threshold for consecutive in F3:AI3
`=SUM((FREQUENCY(IF(F3:AI3>=0,COLUMN(F3:AI3)),IF(F3:AI3<0,COLUMN(F3:AI3)))>=2)*1)`

suppose I want count of values more than 10 in groups of 5 and more then
`=SUM((FREQUENCY(IF(F3:AI3>=10,COLUMN(F3:AI3)),IF(F3:AI3<10,COLUMN(F3:AI3)))>=5)*1)`

hope this helps